# Incrementar valores en un array mediante parámetros pasados por teclado

Tags: php, array

tengo un array con letras del abecedario y la idea es que mediante un formulario donde se teclea letra y numero, se desplace la letra elegida el numero de veces que se inserta.

Este es el código php:

```
 <?php
$letras = array
(
0 => "a",
1 => "b",
2 => "c",
3 => "d",
4 => "e",
5 => "f",
6 => "g",
7 => "h",
8 => "i",
9 => "j",
10 => "k",
11 => "l",
12 => "m",
13 => "n",
14 => "ñ",
15 => "o",
16 => "p",
17 => "q",
18 => "r",
19 => "s",
20 => "t",
21 => "u",
22 => "v",
23 => "w",
24 => "x",
25 => "y",
26 => "z"
);

$letra = $_POST['letra'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];

//echo $letra;
//echo $numero;
$var=array_search($letra,$letras);

print_r ($var); 

foreach ($letras as $clave => $valor) 
{
    if ($letra == $valor)
    {
        echo "encontrado";
        
    }
}

echo "<br>";
echo "<br>";
print_r ($letras);
?>
```

El html simplemente es para insertar la letra y el número.

El funcionamiento es así: Introduzca letra: a  Introduzca numero: 3
esto da como resultado: d, ya que a se ha desplazado 3 veces.

Tal como esta ahora cuando introduzco una letra me localiza la posición pero no se como hacer para que cuando introduzca el numero, incremente la posición y me muestre la nueva posición.
Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
 
$letras = array
(
0 => "a",
1 => "b",
2 => "c",
3 => "d",
4 => "e",
5 => "f",
6 => "g",
7 => "h",
8 => "i",
9 => "j",
10 => "k",
11 => "l",
12 => "m",
13 => "n",
14 => "ñ",
15 => "o",
16 => "p",
17 => "q",
18 => "r",
19 => "s",
20 => "t",
21 => "u",
22 => "v",
23 => "w",
24 => "x",
25 => "y",
26 => "z"
);

$letra = $_POST['letra'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];


$index=array_search($letra,$letras)+$numero;


print_r ($letras[$index]);//esto te va imprimir la letra cuando aumente, si colocas a y numero 3 te imprime d
?>
```

Comment: Vaya, pensaba que había que montar un bucle, muchas gracias compañero!

Comment: si resolvió tu pregunta marca como respondida y puedes botar a favor mi respuesta